# Not whitelisted URL Inline Videos not playing in Android 4.4 and Cordova 3.2

Tags: android, html, url, cordova, whitelist

I am trying to play a video inline in my Hybrid application using an HTML5 video tag. The source for the video is an 'External URL' and is working fine without whitelisting in Android 4.3. But the same is not working in Android 4.4.2 . IS there any changes in Android 4.4 related to whitelisting of URLs. I cannot whitelist URL for my requirements.

I am working on Cordova 3.2, Nexus 7, Android 4.4.2. Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Have you tried one of the videoplayer plugins for playing video natively?

Comment: This is about Whitelisting URLs. When I give permission for accessing the video using <access origin="http://urlname">, then the video plays without issues.I am not sure why should I choose video player plugin?. I might still get the same issue with the VideoPlayer as no permission is given.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it is possible that playing the video natively will not require whitelisting, since it wont be accessed via the webview